# Are the same security issues present when using eval(raw_input()) instead of input()?

Tags: security, python-2.7, input, eval

I was reading up on Python a few days ago, and I learned about the security issues related to Python 2.7's `input()` function. Now from what I've heard, `eval(raw_input())` is the equivalent, does it pose the same security issues that `input()` does?

Comment: per https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input, input is equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))... so you can drop the pretty much and say yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and for exactly the same reasons, so don't do it. Parse your input with something that handles the specific input format you're expecting, not by evaluating the input as Python code.